Cant build HelloWebView sample (webview2) code in an existing win32 native application codebase. Running HelloWebView sample standalone is successfull
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\implements.h(65): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an errorC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\implements.h(813): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Microsoft::WRL::CloakedIid' being compiledC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\implements.h(1307): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Microsoft::WRL::Details::AdjustImplementsMicrosoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags<3,true,I0> with [I0=Microsoft::WRL::CloakedIid]' being compiledC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\implements.h(1341): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Microsoft::WRL::ImplementsMicrosoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags<3,Microsoft::WRL::CloakedIid>' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\implements.h(65): warning C5204: 'Microsoft::WRL::CloakedIid': class has virtual functions, but its trivial destructor is not virtual; instances of objects derived from this class may not be destructed correctlyC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\implements.h(65): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\implements.h(1451): warning C4265: 'Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase': class has virtual functions, but its non-trivial destructor is not virtual; instances of this class may not be destructed correctly
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared\intsafe.h(179): warning C4005: 'LONGLONG_MIN': macro redefinitionD:\work\code.tally\sa_infra\slib.basic\src\common\defines.h(92): note: see previous definition of 'LONGLONG_MIN'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared\intsafe.h(219): warning C4005: 'LONGLONG_MAX': macro redefinitionD:\work\code.tally\sa_infra\slib.basic\src\common\defines.h(91): note: see previous definition of 'LONGLONG_MAX'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared\intsafe.h(224): warning C4005: 'ULONG64_MAX': macro redefinitionD:\work\code.tally\db_infra\slib.filesys\src\lfscommon.h(35): note: see previous definition of 'ULONG64_MAX'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\wrappers\corewrappers.h(176): warning C4265: 'Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTMicrosoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTraits::MutexTraits': class has virtual functions, but its non-trivial destructor is not virtual; instances of this class may not be destructed correctlyC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\wrappers\corewrappers.h(612): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTMicrosoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTraits::MutexTraits' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\wrappers\corewrappers.h(646): warning C4265: 'Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::Mutex': class has virtual functions, but its non-trivial destructor is not virtual; instances of this class may not be destructed correctly
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\wrappers\corewrappers.h(176): warning C4265: 'Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTMicrosoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTraits::SemaphoreTraits': class has virtual functions, but its non-trivial destructor is not virtual; instances of this class may not be destructed correctlyC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\wrappers\corewrappers.h(650): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTMicrosoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTraits::SemaphoreTraits' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\wrappers\corewrappers.h(684): warning C4265: 'Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::Semaphore': class has virtual functions, but its non-trivial destructor is not virtual; instances of this class may not be destructed correctly
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\wrappers\corewrappers.h(176): warning C4265: 'Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTMicrosoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTraits::EventTraits': class has virtual functions, but its non-trivial destructor is not virtual; instances of this class may not be destructed correctlyC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\wrappers\corewrappers.h(688): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTMicrosoft::WRL::Wrappers::HandleTraits::EventTraits' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt\wrl\wrappers\corewrappers.h(707): warning C4265: 'Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::Event': class has virtual functions, but its non-trivial destructor is not virtual; instances of this class may not be destructed correctly
src/browser/browserview.cpp(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wil/com.h': No such file or directory
HelloWebView was able to run fine standalone.
But copying the HelloWebView.cpp in win32 native project, got above build errors.
